# Is there in fact a race condition with systemd units specifying "After=suspend.target"

Tags: systemd

In [Debian bug report about starting anacron on resume](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744753#124), there is the claim that this snippet (simplified for brevitiy) might be triggered while suspending instead of on resuming, because of the way the systemd dependencies work. I am unable to understand the race condition indicated there using the systemd documentation and the unit files shipped with systemd.

```
[Unit]
Description=Do something at resume
After=suspend.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/do-something

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

The author of this post goes on citing `systemd-suspend.service`, which contains the following declarations (again trimmed down to the relevant statements)

```
[Unit]
After=sleep.target
Requires=sleep.target
```

followed by the claim that two different units, both ordering after `sleep.target` are run in parallel and thus there is no ordering between those two units. I perfectly agree on that point, but *there are no two units both depending on `sleep.target`*, as I understand it. The declaration in `systemd-suspend.service` makes sure that `sleep.target` is completely started before going to sleep, so all units that are depended-on by `sleep.target` are started. But looking at `suspend.target` (the target the original unit file really depends on), I find the following declarations:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=systemd-suspend.service
After=systemd-suspend.service
```

I understand this file as declaring the `suspend.target` is sucessfully started only after `systemd-suspend.service` is sucessfully started. Now, looking into `systemd-suspend.service` again, I find the following declarations in that file:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
Exec=/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend
```

As I understand one-shot services, they do not enter the "started" state until the `Exec` command finished. So anything ordering `After` this service can not get started until `systemd-sleep` finished. Finally, taking a look at systemd-sleep, it contains the magic write of some string to `/sys/power/state`, which blocks until the system is resumed. This should ensure that everything that wants to be started after `systemd-suspend.service` is indeed not started before resume.

The reason that I claim that writing to `/sys/power/state` blocks is that this write is handled by [the sysfs store function for that file](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/power/main.c#n427), which calls [`pm_suspend`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/power/suspend.c#n552) for non-hibernate modes, which in turn calls `enter_state` (directly before `pm_suspend` in the same source file) which obviously doesn't return before resuming.

Comment: For something that is a potentially a bug in systemd, I recommend contacting the systemd developers directly to discuss it.

Comment: I'm not claiming there is a race condition *within* systemd. I want to know whether I undestood some concepts of systemd (namely "one-shot" services and "After" ordering) correctly, in which case the statement I quoted, and that seems to be un-disputed in different Debian bugs, would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; [post #124](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744753#124) is wrong.

There is a problem that people sometimes write units `WantedBy=sleep.target` `After=sleep.target`.  This will start the unit before sleep, and then not wait for them to finish before going to sleep, which is almost certainly not what they were trying to do.  It's possible that's what the poster was thinking of.

Authority: I independently wrote a unit like this to run hdparm on resume, based on a similar analysis.  It works fine, just as the response in [post #129](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744753#129) says.  My unit runs correctly every time.  I know, because if I run *without* it, I can hear the clicks from my hard drive.  Earlier, I was able to identify a [bug in udev](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5903) that caused my previous solution to be unreliable, solely because I noticed hearing the clicks.